# Why I can't find 'angular' in in a module with angularAMD?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-amd

I'm working with AngularAMD and I'm trying to "load" angular.easypichart module.

Here is my architecture:

```
--js
----app.js
----main.js
--lib
----angular.easypiechart.js
----ngload.js
```

In my **main.js** I've got that code:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        'angular': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular',
        'angular-route': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-route',
        'angularAMD': 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.amd/0.2/angularAMD.min',
        'ngload': '../lib/ngload',
        'easypiechart': '../lib/angular.easypiechart'
    },
    shim: {
        'angularAMD': ['angular'],
        'angular-route': ['angular'],
        'ngload': ['angularAMD'],
        'easypiechart': ['angular']
    },
    deps: ['app']
});
```

And in my **app.js** :

```
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route', 'easypiechart'], function (angularAMD) {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('guess-bg', ['ngRoute']);
    // config, etc.

    return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
});
```

But `'easypiechart'` fail and I get the error  `Cannot read property 'module' of undefined`

I don't get it because I used ['angular'] in shim for easypiechart.

I tried a lot of things such as

```
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route', 'ngload!easypiechart']
```

Or

```
var app = angular.module('guess-bg', ['ngRoute', 'easypiechart']);
```

But keep getting errors. It's very obscur to me and I don't even understand how this 'ngload' works. I had no issues with `angular-route` by the way.

Anyway, I don't know how to simply load this module and it's really annoying...

Could you tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Could you please tell where exactly this ```'Cannot read property 'module' of undefined'``` come from? Is it from your ```app.js``` or is it from ```angular.easypiechart.js```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't even understand how this 'ngload' works

You don't need `ngload` if you want to load module directly in your first requireJS module. It is mostly use for lazy load module for your app, for example in `/some/random/route/` you want to use an angular module, but only want it to be loaded here. `ngload` will do the trick.

> But 'easypiechart' fail and I get the error  Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

In your `app.js` try to remove `'use strict';` :

```js
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route', 'easypiechart'], function (angularAMD) {

    var app = angular.module('guess-bg', ['ngRoute', 'easypiechart']);
    // config, etc.

    return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
});
```

It may because your enable `strict` mode. So browser found that `angular` object wasn't defined anywhere around in `app.js` therefore you got error of `Cannot read property 'module' of undefined`.

In another words, `angular` object does defined and available globally. But since you are in strict mode browser reject to use such global variable. If you still want to use strict mode. Use `window.angular` instead :

```js
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route', 'easypiechart'], function (angularAMD) {
    'use strict';

    var app = window.angular.module('guess-bg', ['ngRoute', 'easypiechart']);
    // config, etc.

    return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
});
```